# version difference between client (1.24) and server (1.20) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1

Tags: windows, kubernetes, kubectl

I use Windows and I've just downloaded kubectl using link from this instruction: [Install and Set Up kubectl on Windows](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-windows/)

But when I check the version I see a warning:

```
C:\>kubectl version
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced
         with the output from kubectl version --short.
         Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.

Client Version: version.Info{
                Major:"1", 
                Minor:"24", 
                GitVersion:"v1.24.0", 
                GitCommit:"4ce5a8954017644c5420bae81d72b09b735c21f0",
                GitTreeState:"clean", 
                BuildDate:"2022-05-03T13:46:05Z", 
                GoVersion:"go1.18.1",
                Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"
                }
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: version.Info{
                Major:"1", 
                Minor:"20", 
                GitVersion:"v1.20.7",
                GitCommit:"132a687512d7fb058d0f5890f07d4121b3f0a2e2", 
                GitTreeState:"clean", 
                BuildDate:"2021-05-12T12:32:49Z", 
                GoVersion:"go1.15.12", 
                Compiler:"gc", 
                Platform:"linux/amd64"
                }
WARNING: version difference between client (1.24) and server (1.20)
         exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
```

- Should I worry about it?
- If so, how can I fix it?
- What is the `server` version?
- Is it somehow related to `~/.kube/config` file?

Comment: buy the way version 1.20.7 is known as one with security issues and was removed from a few cloud vendors so check it, but again not related to your problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Server version is the version of Kubernetes the control plane is running.

Client version is the version of your `kubectl`.

The recommendation is that you keep the two as close as possible to prevent discrepancies between API versions.

For example, if you did a `kubectl create --dry-run=client` with a 1.24.0 kubectl, it would produce output that is valid for 1.24.0 kubernetes, but the apis it refers to may not be recognised by a 1.20.7 cluster.

Your server is 1.20.7, and your client is 1.24.0. To remove this error, you need to downgrade your kubectl to 1.20.7 while interacting with this server. OR upgrade your cluster to 1.24.0

Comment: Please answer directly to those questions:

What is the server version?
Is it somehow related to ~/.kube/config file?

AFAIK client could be connected to any server. What server is mentioned in the output of this command ? from  ~/.kube/config file?

Comment: As per the answer: server version is the version of kubernetes running on the cluster control plan. To answer your other questions: server version is not connected to your local kubeconfig. The server mentioned is the one your active kubectl context is pointing to. Use `kubectl config get-contexts` to list the configured contexts, and the active one is the one with the "*"