# Fix kubectl version skew

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to fix version difference between client (1.21) and server (1.24).
1.21 version for client is desired version.
So version for server shall be decreased.

```
$ kubectl version --short  
Client Version: v1.21.14  
Server Version: v1.24.3  
WARNING: version difference between client (1.21) and server (1.24) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
```

Comment: Then you will need to tear down your kubernetes servers and re-install them using the earlier version of kubernetes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [version difference between client (1.24) and server (1.20) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72760471/version-difference-between-client-1-24-and-server-1-20-exceeds-the-supported)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solved the issue thanks to [larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks)'s advice.

I uninstalled latest version and installed `v1.23.2` of minikube.
Then kubernetes server version `v1.22.2` was intalled.

Not only stop minikube but also delete it is needed to overwrite it's version.

```
$ minikube stop
$ minikube delete
$ curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/v1.23.2/minikube-linux-amd64
$ sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
$ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.21.14
Server Version: v1.22.2
```

WARNING disappeared.

Refference

- [minikube start](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/)

Comment: After that, I found `--kubernetes-version` option. It is easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

you should update the client version, and keep multiple version of `kubectl` base on the cluster. or if you are going to decrease version of `kubectl server` then consider the comment, which i do not think what you will need.

you can use [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) tool version manager, almost a similar tool like tfswitch.

For mac

```
brew install asdf
```

> Manage multiple runtime versions with a single CLI tool

[getting-started](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html) or [install-asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_3-install-asdf)

```
asdf plugin-add kubectl
asdf install kubectl 1.24.3
asdf global kubectl 1.24.3
asdf list kubectl
#already installed list
#1.21.3
#1.23.3
#1.24.3
source ~/.zshrc
```

[image]

to use kubectl from `asdf` run this for  zsh, as you might be using kubectl from other source

```
echo -e "\n. $(brew --prefix asdf)/libexec/asdf.sh" >> ${ZDOTDIR:-~}/.zshrc
```

[getting-started-shell](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_3-install-asdf)

or you can checklist of all available version

```
asdf list all kubectl
```